# web3 contract TypeError: 'apply' is not a function

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, cpp-ethereum

I'm Trying to call the apply function on the contract ABI but I'm getting:

**TypeError: 'apply' is not a function
    at :1:1**

```
> myContract
{
  abi: [{
      constant: false,
      inputs: [{...}],
      name: "apply",
      outputs: [],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "nonpayable",
      type: "function"
  }, {
      constant: true,
      inputs: [{...}],
      name: "getApplicationID",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function"
  }],
  eth: {},
  at: function(address, callback),
  getData: function(),
  new: function()
}

var abi = [{"constant": false,"inputs":[{"name": "hash","type": "bytes32"}],"name": "apply","outputs": [],"payable": false,"stateMutability": "nonpayable","type": "function"},{"constant": true,"inputs": [{"name": "email","type": "string"}],"name": "getApplicationID","outputs":[{"name": "","type": "uint256"}],"payable": false,"stateMutability": "view","type": "function"}]
var myContract = web3.eth.contract(abi,"0xcbbfbafedb0eb83016d2a96a4e80d30b20fa3e30");
 myContract.apply("4183f3a48d92d7b874e0e2dc0353e29aee0031b0a174be6f6a2e7a289e9febca");
```

Comment: Is this `web3.js 1.0.0`? If so, I think you might need `myContract.methods.apply(...)`.

Comment: > web3.version
{
  api: "0.20.1",
  ethereum: "0x3f",
  network: "9876",
  node: "Geth/v1.7.3-stable/darwin-amd64/go1.9.2",
  whisper: undefined,
  getEthereum: function(callback),
  getNetwork: function(callback),
  getNode: function(callback),
  getWhisper: function(callback)
}
>

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var myContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);


var myContractInstance = myContract.at("0xcbbfbafedb0eb83016d2a96a4e80d30b20fa3e30");


var result = myContractInstance.apply("4183f3a48d92d7b874e0e2dc0353e29aee0031b0a174be6f6a2e7a289e9febca");
console.log(result)
```

---

From **[web3.eth.contracts](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract)**

Comment: When I run on terminal I'm getting:                                                         
   Error: exceeds block gas limit
    at web3.js:3143:20
    at web3.js:6347:15
    at web3.js:5081:36
    at web3.js:4137:16
    at apply (<native code>)
    at web3.js:4223:16
    at <anonymous>:1:14

Comment: But when I run on https://remix.ethereum.org I'm getting invalid address

Comment: Which network do you use?

Comment: Ethereum Ropsten network

Comment: Do you have the same error when you specify gas? `myContractInstance.apply("4183f3a48d92d7b874e0e2dc0353e29aee0031b0a174be6f6a2e7a289e9febca", {gas: 300000})`

Comment: Yes                                                                                                          Error: exceeds block gas limit
    at web3.js:3143:20
    at web3.js:6347:15
    at web3.js:5081:36
    at web3.js:4137:16
    at apply (<native code>)
    at web3.js:4223:16
    at <anonymous>:1:14

Comment: Just FYI, `apply` is *not* a constant function.